# Flex: How to add horizontal axes to a chart?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, actionscript

I have a dynamically created chart and I need to add a horizontal and vertical axis in a script. I can't put the chart into MXML because I'm dynamically changing the chart type, deleting and creating a new chart. Therefore, the variable that I use to create the chart, an instance of chartBase, doesn't have either a horizontalAxis or verticalAxis. How do I assign to them if they don't exist? Should I be using a different type? The graphs I want to use are line, bar, and HLOC and/or candlestick.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll get better results by instantiating your chart as a proper type.

For example, in a component I have a skeleton lineChart setup in the mxml...

```
<mx:LineChart id="lineChart" dataProvider="{chartData}" dataTipFunction="dataTipFunction"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    showDataTips="true"
    />
```

... but you could create it as a variable and add it to the container. Then for the axis I determine the type I want and create and apply them, here's some code I use for the horizontal axis...

```
// Setup new horizontal axis.
switch (hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.dataType)
{
    case "Date":
        var hDtAxis:DateTimeAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
        hDtAxis.title = hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.label;
        hDtAxis.dataUnits = "days";
        hDtAxis.dataInterval = 1;
        hDtAxis.parseFunction = dateParser;
        lineChart.horizontalAxis = hDtAxis;
        break;
    case "Time":
        var hTAxis:DateTimeAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
        hTAxis.title = hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.label;
        hTAxis.dataInterval = 1;
        hTAxis.parseFunction = timeParser;
        lineChart.horizontalAxis = hTAxis;
        break;
    case "Number":
        var hLAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
        hLAxis.title = hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.label;
        hLAxis.interval = 1;
        hLAxis.minimum = 0;
        lineChart.horizontalAxis = hLAxis;
        break;
    default:
        var hCatAxis:CategoryAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        hCatAxis.title = hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.label;
        hCatAxis.dataProvider = schemaUtil.aggregateAndSortCasesAC(chartData, vAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.data, [hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.data]);
        hCatAxis.categoryField = hAxisFieldsComboBox.selectedItem.data;
        lineChart.horizontalAxis = hCatAxis;
}
```

Hope that helps.